# Why is most of the matter in the universe made of hydrogen instead of helium? Or iron?

Tags: big-bang, hydrogen, baryogenesis, exotic-matter

Hydrogen, while being the simplest element, is near a peak of the binding potential curve.  Presumably in the first 1 second or less of the Big Bang timeline, densities and temperatures were such to enable the formation of helium, which is more stable, or iron, which is the most stable.  Why didn't most matter settle into one of these stable states?

Furthermore, it is posited that strange quark matter is the most stable form of matter possible, and may exist in the cores of some neutron stars.  Why didn't most matter form as strange matter even earlier in the timeline, precluding the formation of any less stable form?

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/418563/313823) addresses many aspects of my question, but not all.  Is it accurate to say that, by the time expansion reached a state that with low enough temperature and density for *any* baryons to form, it was already too diluted to form any but single protons (except for the rare dense patch)?   And the question about strange matter still remains.  Thank you.

Comment: As the linked answer says, "Big bang nucleosynthesis makes very precise predictions about the fraction of baryons that end up as protons vs other nuclei". FWIW, BBN (Big Bang Nucleosynthesis) lasted for ~17 minutes, and it was limited by temperature, density, and the availability of neutrons.

Comment: I can only wish that my own most productive times lasted as long as 17 minutes. :)

Comment: *it is posited that strange quark matter is the most stable form of matter possible* A hypothesis without experimental evidence is just a hypothesis.

Comment: I suppose another way to form the strange matter question is, "Those who hold the hypothesis of strange matter and its stability does not seem to find it in conflict with the lack of strange matter produced by the Big Bang.  Thus some aspect of the theory must have prevented it from forming."

Comment: Related: "Why is hydrogen the most abundant element in the Universe?" https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/418550/226902 Also interesting and related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484157/226902